# On a Riemannian manifold, calculate the metric from the distance

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensor

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is it possible to calculate the distance between two points on this manifold. Is it possible the inverse? That means: given a formula of the distance, for example: 
$$d(p,q)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q}\right)^2$$
is it possible to calculate the metric tensor and so define a manifold in which this formula is valid?
Thanks

Comment: Expand for $\vec{q}=\vec{p}+\vec{\epsilon}$.

Comment: A related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37651/riemannian-surfaces-with-an-explicit-distance-function

Comment: It is not difficult to prove that the distance function determines the Riemannian metric, should a Riemannian metric exist with the given distance function. Determining when such a Riemannian metric exists has been considered in the literature, but I can't remember a reference at the moment.

Comment: There's an answer at math.SE that answers this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198721/18934

Comment: It's actually hard to determine if a metric is Riemannian.  But this $d$ violates the triangle inequality with $d(1,4)=d(4,9)=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $d(1,9)=4/\sqrt{2}$, so it's not a metric at all.

Comment: A more general version: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45154/riemannian-metric-induced-by-a-metric